# Create wordpress post featured image from external image

Tags: wordpress

Is there is any way we can add featured image from external source

$image  = "http://example.com/test.jpg";

I want to set this image to my post featured image

Can we do this ??

Regards,

Gurpreet

Comment: I think when you click featured image it gives you abortion to use a url

Answer (score -1):

Check the screenshot its already thr --

[image: Shot]

Comment: @gurpreetsingh if u need to do it via coding then u please explain a little more what exactly u want to achieve via coding ?

Comment: `$image = "http://example.com/test.jpg";
I have Post Id: $post_id = '24';`

is there any way to set a featured image of the post id 24




`

Comment: Let me know is this possible??

Comment: why not ..i think its all possible..but im not clear with your question..please clarify a little more